# Import config.js file in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a config file in js for all my keys.
The problem is that i am not able to export and export the file.
Here is the code and the error:

config.js:

```
export const mailchimpKey ='KEY'
```

app.js:

```
//jshint esversion: 6
const config = require('./config');
```

I have the folowing error when starting my node server:

```
C:\Code\boootstrap\boootstrap\src\newsletter\config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export const mailchimpKey ='KEY'
                                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I read somewhere that I need babel set up to use import/export. Is that true?
I tried installing this but not sure I set it up well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
module.exports={
   mailchimpKey:'KEY'

}
```

Instead of your code in `config.js`