# NODEJS Import config.js from parent folder into module

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm tring to import a config file with the following data:

```
module.exports = webhook_methods = {
GET : "GET",
POST : "POST",
PUT : "PUT"
}
module.exports = endpoints = {
WEBHOOKS : "webhooks",
ORDERS : "orders"
}
```

From a parent folder into my module (webhook_module.js) with the following structure

```
-server.js
-config.js
--webhook_module.js
```

Inside my webhook module I'm importing the config as

```
const {webhook_methods,endpoints} = require('../configs');
```

And using it to fech the data as

```
_fecht_url = `https://${site}/api/${endpoints.WEBHOOKS}.json`;
```

But the error I get is that endpoints and webhook_methods are undefined, so the require did not work, or the export did not work. I can't figure it out...

This is similar to [Import config.js file in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476451/import-config-js-file-in-another-file) but in my case there are two differences I'm not able to solve. My config.js has many exports, not just one, and second it is located on a parent folder.

Would this be easier to be done with config file being typescript? I really just want to create a config file with a bunch of enum objects and import it throughout the project. it's a plus if those enums could be found by VS Code autocomplete.

Comment: You are reassigning `module.exports`. Need to set a property on it `exports.webhook_methods = {}` `exports.endpoints = {}`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, my export in config.js should be

```
module.exports.webhook_methods = {
GET : "GET",
POST : "POST",
PUT : "PUT"
}
module.exports.endpoints = {
WEBHOOKS : "webhooks",
ORDERS : "orders"
}
```